# Can't access to web site after enabling mod_rewrite

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I activated mod_rewrite on my dedicated server : Centos 5.5, after that if I placed any .htaccess in any web site, i can't access the web site from http://site.com/, I have to specify index file, http://site.com/index.php

for example :
I have this web site http://www.floupie.com, the home file is located in http://www.floupie.com/cgi-bin/index.cgi

and I created an .htaccess rule to access it automaticly, but not working :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$                   /cgi-bin/index.cgi [L]
```

I have this problem with all web site in the server.

Help Please

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the apache server. So that your mod_rewrite work